# MacOS Sierra: Why does adding an NSScrollView to a subview change (/corrupt?) the drawing order of superviews?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, macos-sierra, nsscrollview

In my app and in a simpler test case, the addition of an NSScrollView to an NSView inside a view hierarchy appears to be corrupting the order of drawing of the entire view hierarchy (above and outside that NSScrollView). I experience this only on MacOS Sierra, not on Mojave or later (I don't have High Sierra to test), and unfortunately have to fix it on Sierra despite building on Mojave (which means I don't have convenient ability to execute under XCode). While I know Sierra is old news, I suspect this is somehow my bug since view-rendering correctness is fundamental, I'm not in a complicated situation, and Sierra 10.12.6 is pretty mature code.

Can someone give me enough insight into what I have wrong that I can achieve my intended design on Sierra, which is to have a Label (NSTextField) sit **visibly on top of another custom Canvas view,** which in turn embeds a scrollView of unrelated content?

The symptom of the problem is that Sierra incorrectly draws the Label **beneath** the Canvas where the same code on Mojave draws the Label correctly **ontop** the Canvas. In my simplest test case, I have the Canvas (my custom view) and my static Label pre-defined in a Window in Interface Builder, with the Label later than the Canvas in the View order (more "topwards" in the drawing stack) :

[image: Interface Builder: Label ontop MyCanvas]

In MyCanvas's awakeFromNib, I programmatically create a scrollView, add an image to it, and then add it to the Canvas:

```
@implementation MyCanvas

- (void)awakeFromNib { 

    NSImageView *image = [NSImageView imageViewWithImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"bigRedX"]];
    image.frame = CGRectInset(self.frame, 20.0, 5.0);

    #if 1
        /* Embed image in new scrollView embedded in MyCanvas. MyCanvas now draws ontop higher views in Sierra! */
        NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        scrollView.documentView = image;
        [self addSubview: scrollView];
    #else
        /* Embed image directly into MyCanvas. MyCanvas stills draws correctly beneath higher views in Sierra! */
        [self addSubview: image];
    #endif

    ...
}
```

Running the result and resizing the window so the two collide (canvas sticks to top/left window bounds, label sticks bottom/right), I see the following correct behavior in Mojave, Label ontop of Canvas:
[image: Mojave image - good order]

And the corresponding incorrect behavior in Sierra, Canvas ontop of Label:

[image: Sierra image - bad order]

The actual order of views in the window's superview is identical per [NSView _subtreeDescription]. Mojave includes a few new subviews to the NSImageView, NSScrollView, and the NSScrollView's NSClipView, but on both platforms, the two top-level views are in the same and correct order: NSTextField is after (on top of) MyCanvas.

Mojave:

```
Unmanaged<AnyObject>(_value: [   A      w   ] h=--- v=--- NSView 0x100eb1350 f=(0,0,346,295) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x10ad86970>
  [   AF     w   ] h=--& v=&-- MyCanvas 0x100ef7260 f=(34,25,277,250) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x10ad7a280>
    [   AF O   w   ] h=--- v=--- NSScrollView 0x100ef8220 f=(34,33,277,250) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x10ad79940>
      [   A      w   ] h=--- v=--- _NSScrollViewContentBackgroundView 0x10d6f4290 f=(0,0,277,250) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x10ad46800>
        [   A      w   ] h=--- v=--- NSVisualEffectView 0x10d6f7c40 f=(0,0,277,250) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x10ad2bc90>
      [   A      w   ] h=-&- v=-&- NSClipView 0x100ef9110 f=(0,0,277,250) b=(54,38,-,-) => <_NSClipViewBackingLayer: 0x10ad903e0>
        [   A      w   ] h=--- v=--- NSImageView 0x100efa6e0 "<NSImage 0x100fb6120 Name=bigRedX Size={180, 180} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x10108aeb0 Size={180, 180} ColorSpace=DELL 2007FP colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=180x180 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x100ea1260> CGImageSource=0x101507b70"
)>" f=(54,38,237,240) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x10adb3ea0>
          [   A      w   ] h=--- v=--- _NSImageViewSimpleImageView 0x100efb540 f=(29,30,180,180) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x1010e7a80>
  [   AF     w   ] h=&&- v=--& NSTextField 0x100e66f70 "Static Label" f=(125.5,42,213.5,16) b=(-) => <NSTextLayer: 0x10adabcb0>
A=autoresizesSubviews, C=canDrawConcurrently, D=needsDisplay, F=flipped, G=gstate, H=hidden (h=by ancestor), L=needsLayout (l=child needsLayout), U=needsUpdateConstraints (u=child needsUpdateConstraints), O=opaque, P=preservesContentDuringLiveResize, S=scaled/rotated, W=wantsLayer (w=ancestor wantsLayer), V=needsVibrancy (v=allowsVibrancy), #=has surface
)
```

Sierra:

```
Unmanaged<AnyObject>(_value: [   A        U ] h=--- v=--- NSView 0x7fd3f4fe9920 f=(0,0,339,319) b=(-) TIME drawRect: min/mean/max 0.00/0.00/0.00 ms
  [   AF       U ] h=--& v=&-- MyCanvas 0x7fd3f9f8af50 f=(34,49,277,250) b=(-) TIME drawRect: min/mean/max 0.00/0.00/0.00 ms
    [   AF O   W U#] h=--- v=--- NSScrollView 0x7fd3f9f22a40 f=(34,33,277,250) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x7fd3f4eef4c0> TIME drawRect: min/mean/max 0.00/0.00/0.00 ms
      [   A  O   w U ] h=--- v=--- NSClipView 0x7fd3f9f4cab0 f=(0,0,277,250) b=(54,38,-,-) => <_NSClipViewBackingLayer: 0x7fd3f4ee0c80> TIME drawRect: min/mean/max 0.00/0.00/0.00 ms
        [   A      w U ] h=--- v=--- NSImageView 0x7fd3f4de6320 "<NSImage 0x7fd3f4de6020 Name=bigRedX Size={180, 180} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x7fd3f9f213f0 Size={180, 180} ColorSpace=DELL 2007FP colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=180x180 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x7fd3f9901200> CGImageSource=0x7fd3f9f973f0"
)>" f=(54,38,237,240) b=(-) => <_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x7fd3f4ef40c0> TIME drawRect: min/mean/max 0.00/0.00/0.00 ms
  [   AF       U ] h=&&- v=--& NSTextField 0x7fd3f9bd81e0 "Static Label" f=(122,42,210,16) b=(-) TIME drawRect: min/mean/max 0.00/0.00/0.00 ms
A=autoresizesSubviews, C=canDrawConcurrently, D=needsDisplay, F=flipped, G=gstate, H=hidden (h=by ancestor), L=needsLayout (l=child needsLayout), U=needsUpdateConstraints (u=child needsUpdateConstraints), O=opaque, P=preservesContentDuringLiveResize, S=scaled/rotated, W=wantsLayer (w=ancestor wantsLayer), V=needsVibrancy (v=allowsVibrancy), #=has surface
)
```

Finally, I'm pointing a suspicious finger at NSScrollView because if I abandon the scrollView, and instead embed the bigRedX directly into MyCanvas rather than embed it into a scrollView and embed that in myCanvas, the Canvas containing bigRedX draws properly beneath the Label on Sierra as well as Mojave.  (This case differs codewise only by changing #if 1 to #if 0 in the snippet above.) And I suspect it's a problem in actual drawing order, rather than clipping, because if I substitute for MyCanvas a transparent backdrop rather than an opaque one, I can see Label "beneath" the Canvas on Sierra where it should be ontop. But how can I get that to happen even when I've got a scrollView in my Canvas?

Thanks for any light you can shed!

Comment: I tried your code on macOS 10.13. It looks ok but if I switch the core animation layer of the content view of the window off in IB then the label is behind the scroll view.

Comment: @Willeke interesting and thanks both for the High Sierra datapoint and the effort to build a duplicate project! Turning Core Animation Layer on---it was off---gives me the behavior I want for Sierra too SOMETIMES. My window is the basic document window of my app and I can create multiple instances of it -- with Core Animation layer switched on, depending on launch, there seems to be a ~50% chance one window will work on Sierra (layers rendered as in nib) and a 0% chance any other window (initialized from the same nib and ViewController) will. Some crazy indeterminacy!

Comment: I will read up on Core Animation Layer and see if I can come up with a rational explanation...it seems definitely implicated. But meanwhile still open for input or further guidance! Thanks, Nick